# Convergence of the series - best criertion

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

What will be the best criterion to use to investigate convergence of the series (i do not need step by step explaination)
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{\frac{1}{n}} }{n^{e}}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, Riemann comparisons, as for $n \geq 1$,
$$e^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq e \leq 3$$
and
$$\frac{1}{n^e} \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$$